# Can't Insert 2009-03-08 into timestamp field

Tags: mysql

Given the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `timestamp_test` (
  `timestamp_test_id` bigint(18) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp_test_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp_test_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the following data:

```
INSERT INTO `timestamp_test` VALUE (0,'2009-03-09 02:07:01');
INSERT INTO `timestamp_test` VALUE (0,'2009-03-08 02:07:01');
```

### Please tell me why I can insert the first date but not the second date?

MySQL version: 5.5

EDIT:
The error I am receiving is:

```
[SQL] 
INSERT INTO `timestamp_test` VALUE (0,'2009-03-08 02:07:01');
[Err] 1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-08 02:07:01' for column 'timestamp_test_date' at row 1
```

Comment: I've already tested exact copies of the code I've posted. The second date is failing, but the first is working.

Comment: Do you have any unknown characters in your second date string? That might cause the date to not parse correctly.

Comment: @CameronTinker I thought of that. So I typed out the values by hand and still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TIMESTAMP` data type is time-zone aware.  The input time is converted from your session's time zone to UTC prior to being stored as an integer, and converted back to your session's time zone on `SELECT`.

In many time zones, **there was no 2009-03-08 02:07:01**, because the clock changed from 01:59:59 to 03:00:00 on that morning, and you are getting this error because whatever your session's current time zone is... was one of those time zones.

Note how the time gets pushed forward if you try to convert this value from/to the same time zone in a DST-observing time zone.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2009-03-08 02:07:01','EST5EDT','EST5EDT');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2009-03-08 02:07:01','EST5EDT','EST5EDT') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2009-03-08 03:00:00                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is incorrect, it should be `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO `timestamp_test` VALUE (0,'2009-03-08 02:07:01');
                                  ^--- missing S
```

As for why you can't insert the 2nd value, you're causing a primary key violation by inserting TWO records with the SAME id value: `0`.

Comment: `VALUE` is acceptable syntax when inserting a single record. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: The document you linked is for MySQL 5.6. You said you were using 5.5 but it is still valid for version 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

If your first column is auto incrementing, you don't need to explicitly set it when you do your insert:

```
INSERT INTO timestamp_test(timestamp_test_date) VALUES ('2009-03-09 02:07:01');
INSERT INTO timestamp_test(timestamp_test_date) VALUES ('2009-03-08 03:00:00');
```

`VALUE` singular is valid as stated in the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Also, as mentioned, the date `2009-03-08 02:07:01` did not happen in several timezones due to daylight savings taking effect at 2am on that date thus making it `2009-03-08 03:00:00`.

Comment: Downvoter, please care to explain why you downvoted? This is correct according to the MySQL official docs.

Comment: They are observations that don't answer the question the OP asked nor explain any errors. The only one who addressed the question is Michael - sqlbot.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the daylight savings issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to insert two records with the same primary key, and that you're using `VALUE` in the place of `VALUES`. Update your `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO `timestamp_test` VALUES (0, '2009-03-09 02:07:01');
INSERT INTO `timestamp_test` VALUES (1, '2009-03-08 02:07:01');
```

Comment: Nope, on an `auto_increment` field using a zero will tell the field to use the next available increment.